# Wrong date stored when taking a screenshot

Tags: cyanogenmod, screenshots, date-and-time

I have a Galaxy Nexus running CyanogenMod 10.2.1 (IIRC that's the last official stable version released). Beside both being quite old they're working for years without any big issue, but yesterday I found something strange: since sometime between 2019-01-02T21:38:35-0300 and 2019-01-03T08:47:13-0300 it started storing wrong dates from screenshot creation times like this:

[image: Info about a screenshot taken in year 2019 but stored as it was taken in the year 50980]

It's quite easy to understand how it's getting this weird date: it's taking the Unix timestamp and multiplying it by 1000. I tried to track down the issue by checking the source code: there was a change on GlobalScreenshot.java [some years ago](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_frameworks_base/commit/47611240bf601821823c9a063ed1e90f2182af40), although it don't explains why this bug started happening just now.

By now I only saw screenshots with the wrong date, so in the best case it will not cause issues to apps or other parts of the system. It's also not causing issues when synchronizing files using MTP (beside the date being something like ‎"29 ‎November, ‎1983").

Is it similar to the Y2K problem? Should I worry about this? If I should what can I do?

Comment: Can you pull one of the screenshot files to your computer and inspect the file info?  Is the "created time" information what you expect there?

Comment: @CzarMatt Using MTP: https://i.imgur.com/W9s6ZXE.png The file name contains the timestamp of when I took the screenshot, created and accessed dates were the ones when I pulled the file and the modified date is bugged.